# Constrained optimization with gradient descent

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, constrained-optimization

Suppose I want to maximize the likelihood $L(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ for some constraint for example $\theta_1 + \theta_2 = 1$ and no other constraints

1. Can I just replace $\theta_2$ by $1 - \theta_1$ in the likelihood then do gradient descent on $\theta_1$. If I can, or cannot, why?
2. Can I set up an objective function with Lagrange multiplier $\mathcal{L} = L(\theta_1, \theta_2) + \lambda (\theta_1 + \theta_2 - 1)$ and do a gradient descent algorithm on $\mathcal{L}$? If I can, or cannot, why?
3. Do I only can rely on [projected gradient descent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272578/solving-constrained-optimization-problem-projected-gradient-vs-dual) if I want to solve this constrained optimization problem using gradient descent?

EDIT: I tried all 3 options and maybe my likelihood function is not "regular" and only option 3 works :'( I would like to know why and when options 1 and 2 work.

Thank you very much in advance for all the help.

Comment: The first option is fine. The second option, you'll need an absolute value in in there.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thanks for your comment. I wonder where I need an absolute value. Btw I tried all 3 options and maybe my likelihood function is not "regular" and only option 3 works :'( I would like to know why and when options 1 and 2 work.

Comment: You can try reparameterizing ,see https://vene.ro/blog/mirror-descent.html

Answer (score 1):

The first option is still constrained as $\theta_1$ still has to lie between $(0,1)$

You can look at the following reparametrization to convert the constrained problem into a truly unconstrained optimization:

Let $\log \theta_1 = \alpha_1 - \log (e^{\alpha_1}+e^{\alpha_2})$ and $\log \theta_2 = \alpha_2 - \log (e^{\alpha_1}+e^{\alpha_2})$. As you can notice, that this reparametrization still preserves the constraint as $\theta_1 = \frac{e^{\alpha_1}}{e^{\alpha_1}+e^{\alpha_2}}$ and $\theta_2 = \frac{e^{\alpha_2}}{e^{\alpha_1}+e^{\alpha_2}}$. Here, $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ have no constraints.

This is called the [log-sum-exp](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book1.html) trick and one place where I know it has been used was the [gradient based estimation of Gaussian Mixture models](https://www.aaai.org/Library/ICML/2003/icml03-088.php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and helpful reference. But I think I mentioned that there is no other constraint :'(

Comment: The problem formulation didn't say that $\theta_1$ has to be greater than 0.